# bidimensional arraylists and inputting another array into them through a loop

Tags: java, arrays, input, arraylist

I am trying to make an arraylist of which are essentially the rows of secondArr (which is a bidimensional arraylist). the problem is that when my `cScore.size() == 7 (or equal to secondArr.size(),` it does not get added to allScore, instead at the end all (in this case 21, as`myArr.size()=3`, and `secondArr.size()=7`. values are added to one index, does anyone know why this is happening? the code seems to be so simple yet it is failing me. So in the end I would want a arraylist of 3 columns and 7 rows (but in this case just 1 column and 7 rows, and once I get this to work then I will add the rest.)

My code is as follows (this is just a small tidbit):

```
    int rowsNum = allScores.size();
    int colsNum = allScores.get(0).size();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(colsNum);
    for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < colsNum; rowIdx++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<Integer>(rowsNum);
        for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < rowsNum; colIdx++) {  
            rows.add(allScores.get(colIdx).get(rowIdx)); {
    }
            result.add(rows);
    }
```

//using the syntax prov. by msi....

the original array allScores is:
[[2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2],[ 2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
when it is transposed with this it reeesults in
[[2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]]

Comment: could you post a more complete code example? And please remove the printouts for readability

Comment: Don't understand this code at first glance... `candScore`, `allScore`, `allScores`? WTF !? What you have and what you want to get, give an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
candScore.add(secondArr.get(j).get(k));
```

shouldn't that be:

```
cScore.add(secondArr.get(j).get(k));
```

Plus I have the feeling that your two nested loops should be the other way around.

```
for (int j=0; j< secondArr.size(); j++){
    for (int k=0; k< myArr.size(); k++) {
```

Comment: No the loops are correct, and I just tried switching them and still allScores is empty with 21 indices

Comment: what is candScore? where in your code are you adding values to cScore?

Comment: candScore was a type, it was meant to be cScore (and is fixed now).
cScore.add(secondArr.get(j).get(k));
is where the values are being added to cScore (and they are being added according to my println error checking)

Comment: perhaps you should use allScores.addAll(cScore); I'm still not sure what your program should do

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your bug lies, but my guess is:

- maybe the order of your two-dimensional array (i.e. it is 7 x 3 instead of 7 x 3)
- do you really need that many ArrayLists to implement your algorithm
- improve your code quality, e.g. by avoiding magic numbers (7 instead of size()), using [extended for loops](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) and assertions will drastically ease finding the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you want. This code transposes 2d arraylists so column will become row, and row
will become column after transposition.

Example:

`[[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]] -> [[1 4 7], [2 5 8], [3 6 9]]`

this code assumes that all rows/columns have the same length.

```
    // arr2d is ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
    int rowsNum = arr2d.size();
    int colsNum = arr2d.get(0).size();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(colsNum);
    for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < colsNum; rowIdx++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<Integer>(rowsNum);
        for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < rowsNum; colIdx++) {
            rows.add(arr2d.get(colIdx).get(rowIdx));
        }
        result.add(rows);
    }
```

... edit (answer to 1st comment)

I don't see your point. Check:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr2d = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    arr2d.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(2));
    arr2d.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(2));
    arr2d.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(2));
    arr2d.get(0).add(1);
    arr2d.get(0).add(2);
    arr2d.get(1).add(3);
    arr2d.get(1).add(4);
    arr2d.get(2).add(5);
    arr2d.get(2).add(6);
```

above gives you: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] -> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]` transformation. There are no copies of rows or columns you are talking about.

Comment: That is very close, but it prints the first row 7 times (only partially transposed you could say?) as opposed to the first row being column 1, the second being column 2, and so forth. (the original had 3 rows and 7 columns). Atleast this gives me a lead on where to go forth with this, thanks msi!

Comment: I have and have done as such, I dont follow the code 100% but could it be it only works when the one dimension > that the other of the orig.?

Comment: @DaxDurax but `[[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]] -> [[1 4 7], [2 5 8], [3 6 9]]` works fine too (cols == rows)